# AdapterRAM property not showing correct value for discrete card

Tags: gpu, wmi, intel, video-card, memory-size

I’m trying to display the graphics card(Integrated & Discrete) related information using WMI in a c# application.
I’m using [Win32_VideoController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-videocontroller) class in which `AdapterRAM` property will get the memory size of the graphics card.
It was showing the correct values for the discrete cards like NVIDIA, AMD. But when tried with IntelArc card which has size of around 6 GB, it is still showing as 1 GB.

For other NVIDIA cards, say example NVIDIA 3060 TI which has size of 8GB, it shows only approx. 4GB.
[image: NVIDIA memory size]
When referred to msdn site for VideoController class, the property AdapterRAM is of `unit32_t` type so it could not return values beyond 4GB.
Is there any other property to refer and get the correct memory size value?

Comment: What does this code detect for your graphics card memory? https://github.com/GameTechDev/gpudetect (GPUDetect.cpp). Even if you use another language and API, it could help to find out the culprit.

Comment: I didn't check with this code yet. But even then, it tells only about Intel. What can be done for other cards like NVIDIA, AMD which have greater size than 4 GB??

Comment: I think for Nvidia and AMD there are good APIs available to fall back. Perhaps the ones, which work for Intel will work for all.